# Required sample size of CFA using power analysis from semPower

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I want to conduct a **confirmatory factor analysis** (CFA) for a model with 4 latent variables and 60 indicator variables (15 per factor, uncorrelated factors, hence **1,710 degrees of freedom**, that is, 1830 covariances minus 120 model parameters).
Using the *semPower* package (A priori power analysis: https://sempower.shinyapps.io/sempower/), I tried to find the **required sample size** for a meaningful analysis. The tool came up with a required ***n* of 37**. This seems incredibly small to me since common rules of thumb suggest a minimum of 5, but ideally 20 observations per indicator variable (that would be min. 300 and better 1,200 observations).

Am I using the power analysis tool wrong? I used the following inputs: alpha = .05, power = .8, effect size = 0.05, df = 1710, #indicators = 60, effect measure = RMSEA for the tool.